# Meteor js http remote api access : what am i doing wrong here?

Tags: meteor, remote-access

Its very simple meteor sketch, I am trying to make a remote api call here, to access [envato api](http://marketplace.envato.com/api/documentation)

but all i am getting is 'undefined'.

I am sure its simple but I just cant figure it out. Any help would be awesome.

Here is the code:

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
        // counter starts at 0
        Session.setDefault("counter", 0);

        Template.hello.helpers({
            counter: function() {
                return Session.get("counter");
            }
        });

        Template.hello.events({
            'click button': function() {
                // increment the counter when button is clicked

                Meteor.call("account", function(error, result) {

                    console.log(result);

                });


                Session.set("counter", Session.get("counter") + 1);
            }
        });
    }

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
        Meteor.startup(function() {
            // code to run on server at startup
        });


        Meteor.methods({
        account: function() {

            // Returns 'undfined' 
            //return HTTP.get("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/USERNAME/APIKEY/account.json").data;

            //works just fine.
            return HTTP.get("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/total-users.json").data;

        }
      });


    }
```

The Interesting thing is it works properly when I use public api sets which do not need USERNAME and APIKEY e.g. http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/total-users.json

I have spent enough time and double checked everything. what I am missing here?? Ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I solved it, as it turns out; just like github.... envato api too needs user agent header; but one can access envato's public API sets without user agent headers.

here is the code:

```
    Meteor.methods({
    account: function() {

        // Returns 'undefined' until user agent header is present... as follows

   result = Meteor.http.get('http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/USERNAME/APIKEY/account.json',{

    headers: {"User-Agent": "Meteor/1.0"}

  });

  return result;

        //following call works just fine without user agent header
        //return HTTP.get("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/total-users.json").data;

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is already synchronous on the server. You can use this for your method instead:

```
Meteor.methods({
    account: function() {
        return HTTP.get("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/USERNAME/APIKEY/account.json").data;
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if that will help your problem, but it will certainly help. Also be sure to have added the `http` package with `meteor add http`

Comment: Thanks Akshat...its still the same 'undefined' should Future be used to try helping it?

Comment: @user1348976 The code I gave you works for me exactly as above. As demoed here: http://meteorpad.com/pad/7J2D6bAWA87QiMKbu. Please also check you've added the http package

Comment: As in the API call on Meteorpad you shared: 

 return HTTP.get("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/total-users.json").data;

worked like charm since start

but the following  API call returns 'Undefined'

return HTTP.get("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/RisingThemes/no1keq2xhphjw9ntgwdq0urav6fdeqm2/account.json").data;

what could be wrong? I have checked there is HTTP packaged and credentials are correct, hit curl http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/RisingThemes/no1keq2xhphjw9ntgwdq0urav6fdeqm2/account.json

works just as expected.